# How to properly center text in a button?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `<button>` to create custom buttons in CSS and the text seems to be centered horizontally and vertically in every browser, without paddings, `text-align` or other properties. All I have to do is change its width and height and the text will be always in the middle.

I was asking myself if this is the default behavior in every browser (even old ones that I didn't had the chance to test) or it would be better to set a `line-height` and paddings to center text vertically and `text-align: center` to center text horizontally, in order to improve compatibility within all browsers.

Comment: If you apply `height`, I would advice you to also add `line-height` with the same value for vertical alignment (IE7-8) ... it will be horizontally centered regardless the `width` in any case (without `text-align`) .. Check http://jsfiddle.net/yv3xqaoy/1/show/ and http://jsfiddle.net/yv3xqaoy/2/show/ with IE7/8 if you can

Comment: Regarding: `if this is the default behavior in every browser`, Form fields and buttons will render differently in every browser as you can see in this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056000/cant-make-my-button-look-the-same-in-different-browsers) Add your own styles If you want to guarantee a certain appearance.

Comment: @Brian : the OP mention `<button>` tag only as far as I can read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the text in `<button>` will always be centered. You just have to play around with `padding` to change its position.

The tag is supported in all major browsers but be caution since different browsers will send different values to it. so it might be different for each browsers.