# How to put text in the center of a button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a CSS button on the top left that goes back to the previous page. However I have problems in centering the text right in the middle, or in this case the arrow in the middle. I've tried all sorts of things, but I can't figure it out. If anyone could help, it would help me a lot.

```css
.goback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: #0077be;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="goback">&#8249;</button>
```

[image: Current page with button]

Comment: text-align: center;

Comment: @i.brod Not working too. :(

Comment: Can you share the image of that button how it looks ?

Comment: @Manjuboyz I did.

Comment: Thank you, just last think, can you add a fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/salmans911/p2f576yr/2/

Comment: @SalmanZR1 I have updated the answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly center text in a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132636/how-to-properly-center-text-in-a-button) or any of the [tens of same questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=center+text+button+%5Bcss%5D) found by searching SO

Comment: @SalmanZR1 I have tweaked some more code, can you let me know if this is what you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.goback {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  background: #0077be;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: .2em;
}
```

```html
<button class="goback">&#8249;</button>
```

So a better solution for you in your case - will be adding padding-bottom;
It's happened because this symbol does not have height = line-height, it has parameters like symbol in lowercase (and for each font, it can be different) and if you want to use this solution - you must make sure for all platform your font will work correctly (sometimes one font has different rendering on macOS and windows)

when I do similar I use for this SVG icon(exact SVG sprite) here you can see realization with pseudo-class and svg(background in base64)

https://jsfiddle.net/csscoder/uj1hqv4o/10/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to just add the padding bottom = 0 and line-height= 0 the icon will be align in center

```
.goback {
   padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
   line-height: 0;
}
```

it will help you out

Comment: This helps, but i still need to go a bit higher. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions, you have to change the `height` and `width` to `85px` if that's not an issue.

what I found was the reason it was not getting into center because the `font-size` and `height and width` were contradicting. I have tried to fix the issue making it to alignment.

if you want height and width to be `80px` then you have to decrease the `font-size` and use the `padding` feature.

UPDATE:

[image]

**CSS snippet**

```
.goback {
   position:absolute;
   top: 20px;
   left: 20px;
   font-size: 65px;  
   width: 85px;
   height: 85px;
   border-radius: 50%;  
   background: #0077be;
   color: #ffffff;   
   border:none;
   padding:0px 5px 20px 0px;   
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Also i recommend you not to use fix height or width, instead you should use padding: 10px 30px;(example value), if you will have longer text, it will auto adjust.